# React: PWA app doesn't work offline for the network URL

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to understand why my react PWA works offline only for the localhost:5000 and not for the network url like 10.0.0.7:5000. 
I haven't touched the serviceworker.js

these are the commands for executing the builded code

```
npm run build

serve -s build
```

Thanks in advance.
Andrea

Comment: Nobody can't reproduce your issue without any actual code. So you need to update it. anyway, I am guessing you need to serve it via `https` because service workers can only be executed over secure contexts https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Offline_Service_workers.

Comment: I have this behaviur with the default code

Comment: By the  way understood if i don't  have a https certificate i cannot test it.

Comment: You can create your own custom SSL certificate. or you can just follow this if you're using CRA https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/ or check the docs for build tool you're using to how to serve the site in HTTPS. You'd get a warning about security but it's irrelevant since it's your own site.